# Remove last character from wxPython wxTextCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython, textctrl

I am trying to remove the very last character from a TextCtrl object in wxPython. I'm using wxPython 2.8.12 and Python 2.7.2.

My code is as follows:

```
def btnBkClicked(self, e):
    self.txtItem.Remove(self, (self.txtItem.GetLastPosition()[-1]), (self.txtItem.GetLastPosition()))
```

However, that doesn't work :( What do I need to change/do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to remove the very last character from the string, try

```
self.txtItem.SetValue(self.txtItem.GetValue()[:-1])
```

This code gets current text from `TextCtrl` and sets and sets its value to this text up to the last symbol.

Regarding your input, `TextCtrl.Remove` needs two parameters: `from` and `to`, which are integer numbers giving the first and the last positions to be removed. As `GetLastPosition` returns the number of characters in the control, your code should be modified as

```
self.txtItem.Remove(self.txtItem.GetLastPosition()-1, self.txtItem.GetLastPosition())
```